# Logstash Docker image

Tags: dockerfile, logstash, kibana

I'm new the here. I have a question I would like to build custom logstash docker image. My docker image should do push logs to kibana dashboard. Do you have suggestions? or does anyone have example dockerfile?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

To push logs into Kibana it could be done if you write a pipeline which takes and input and then directs the output to elasticsearch.

[Logstash pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-create-maintainable-and-reusable-logstash-pipelines)

From the elastic search Kibana could pull the data. Logstash magically cannot push the data using a docker file afaik. So I feel this is the thing which you must do.

1. Deploy Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana.
2. Write a Logstash.conf file which picks input using tcp and output will be sent to where Elasticsearch is hosted
3. Pull the data using Kibana(configure Kibana.yml) and display the data.

You can use the official dockerfile provided by Elastic for Logstash

[Dockerfile of Logstash](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/main/Dockerfile)

Comment: Thank you for answer. My kibana and elastic are running remote server. As I understand I'll try to setup pipeline on my local righ?

Comment: No your logstash pipeline must be present on the remote server